# fill a triangle in the least ammount of pen strokes

Tags: geometry, optimization

Imagine you have a triangle and a bunch of pens of varying sizes. You can place the pen on the paper and lift it up to draw a circle, or place the pen on the paper, then move it in a straight line and lift it up to draw a stadium/capsule. You need to fill most of the triangle in the least pen movements possible. How would I do that?
I could only think of this:

[image: my idea]

The green dots and lines represent where the pen touches the paper and the purple circles represent the pen size (I only did one corner to make the image clearer)

Comment: Do you want to fill as much of the triangle as possible or use the fewest strokes possible? You can't do both at once. If you want some balance of the two, then you should quantitatively define what to optimize.

Comment: @Karl I am trying to have the fewest ammount of movements (it doesn't matter if the pen is up or down) while still filling around 90% of the triangle